# Bind google address autocomplete api on dynamically create input

Tags: jquery, html, autocomplete, google-places-api, google-geolocation

Basically I'm creating dynamical fields for example there may be 10 fields by using the jquery. And I want to add google address autocomplete on all 10 dynamically created fields. But this code is not working.

```
var html += '<div class="form-group">';
html += '<label class="control-label">'+field.label+'</label>';
html += '<input class="form-control address-auto-complete" 

name="'+field.name+'[]" type="text" />';
html += '</div>';
$('#load-case-fields').html(html);
var a = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($('.address-auto-complete'));
```

I'm getting this error with above code.
`InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement`

Answer (score 1):

You can try in pure JS

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zzz4w5cn/) demo

```js
function initialize() {

  parentDiv = document.getElementById('variable');
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { //dynamically create 10 inputs
    var formGroupDiv = document.createElement('div')
    formGroupDiv.classList.add('form-group')
    parentDiv.appendChild(formGroupDiv)
    var labels = document.createElement('label')
    labels.classList.add('control-label')
    labels.innerHTML = 'LABEL ' + i
    formGroupDiv.appendChild(labels)
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.classList.add('form-control', 'address-auto-complete')
    input.setAttribute('placeholder', "Enter your address")
    input.setAttribute('type', "text")
    formGroupDiv.appendChild(input)
  }
  var variableAuto = document.getElementsByClassName('address-auto-complete');
  for (var j = 0; j < variableAuto.length; j++) { //dynamically initialize autocomplete to input elements
    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      (variableAuto[j]), {
        types: ['geocode']
      });
  }

}

initialize();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-sm-12" id="variable">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

$('.selector') gives you an jquery Element, but you want the underlying Input so try $('.asd')[0] or use plain JavaScript

```
var input = document.getElementById('yourInput');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
```